# Samsung galaxy s duos wifi not working

Tags: samsung, wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering, wifi-direct

I am using Samsung Galaxy S DUOS GT-7562, I have rooted my phone few days ago using `UnlockRoot` software. Now from 3-4 days I am having problem with WiFi. Please check the attached images. I have tried so many things which was already there on different forums, but nothing works for me.

My phone's warranty expired on 10th of June and also I have rooted it. So, I will have to pay a huge amount to Service Center.

Any hints what I could do?
Is it a kind of bug or virus?

**Edit**

I have tried,

1) Hard Reset from boot menu

2) Unroot phone from same software, through which I have rooted the phone.. i.e `UnlockRoot`

3) As mentioned in XDA Developers Forum, tried installing different applications which solves such problems like `WifiFixer`

Still the problem is there, Wifi or Portable Wifi or Wifi-Direct are not starting. They are hanged in between On/Off state.

[image] [image] [image] [image]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: Yepp, much clearer now (so I removed my previous comment – you might wish to do the same for yours). // Still open question/suggestion: Have you tried running `adb logcat` while enabling WiFi? That might give some clues (imagine e.g. no MAC being given – unlikely, but in that case no network connections could be activated).

Comment: Sir, Nothing getting displayed in LogCat as Wifi is not getting ON. It's in between On/Off state. Please check screenshot-1

Comment: That's not `adb logcat`. And yes, I see it's not getting on. But screenshot #4 shows an error, so `logcat` definitely will have details. How did you check `logcat`? Your spelling makes me assuming an app, which might not work correctly (depending on Android version and whether it has root or not, it might not be able to really see *all* entries – which is why I explicitely recommended using `adb logcat`. Sorry for not being clear about the background).